# Hashmap - Key: String, Value: Boolean. How do I test the value within an if statement?

Tags: java

```
/ public void getFinishedBooks(HashMap<String, Boolean> library) {

if (library.size() < 1) {

  System.out.println("No books in Library");

} else {

  for (String books : library.keySet()) {

    **if (library.value == true) {**
```

---

I want the bottom IF statement to run if the Hashmap 'value' of data type Boolean is equal to try. I've tried .get() but that's not working.

Comment: "I've tried .get() but that's not working." Well what *exactly* did you try? Presumably you're interested in the value associated with the `books` key... so whatever you do, you'll need to use that. (Alternatively, you could iterate over the `entrySet` instead of the `keySet`...)

Comment: How did you try using `.get()`? `if(library.get(books))` should work just fine. Or did you try to use get on books? (which is a string for a book used as a key, not the map)

Comment: Yes, you should learn how to do it with `get()`, and then try to understand why you'd better use `entrySet()` and get that working.

Comment: Thanks Tezra I was missing the books as the parameter for .get. I'm learning as you can probably guess :)

Comment: @StephenBrown That is ok. That is why in the future, you include what you tried and how it failed, so that we know WHAT you did wrong, (and give you the proper answer)

Comment: It's not `Hashmap`.

Comment: Other ways to write your code: `if (library.isEmpty()) {...`. Also, comparing a `boolean` to a `boolean` to get a `boolean` result, as in `if (value == true)`, is redundantly repetitive and superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code it will work

```
    for (String books : library.keySet()) {
        if(books != null){
        Boolean libValue = library.get(books );
        if (libValuetrue) {
            //added as per your code
        }

        }
    }
```

Comment: The hashmap is <String, Boolean>. `String libValue = library.get(books );` is a type miss-match compiler error.

Comment: Comparing a `boolean` to a `boolean` to get a `boolean` result, as in `if (libValue == true)`, is redundantly repetitive and superfluous.

Comment: The answer lacks treatment of null values for books.

Comment: @Markus added null conditon

Comment: Sorry, I meant for libValue you need to check for null, my fault. Otherwise the if will throw an NPE.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than getting the key set, I'd get the entry set - that means you can iterate over the key/value pairs, rather than having to look up each key again. For example, to print all the books with a `true` value:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Boolean> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getValue()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey());
    }
}
```

Or to handle nullity if your values may be null:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Boolean> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    if (TRUE.equals(entry.getValue()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (library.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("No books in Library");
} else {
    for (String books : library.keySet()) {
         if (library.get(books)) {
```

alternatively

```
    for (Entry<String, Boolean> entry : library.entrySet()) {
         if (entry.getValue()) {
```

However it would have been more ideal to use a `Set<String>`.

```
Set<String> library = new HashSet<>();

if (library.contains(...))
```